# How can I get a weather data for a county?

Tags: weather

There are APIs for accessing the current weather based on latitude and longitude, but I don't see any way to get the latitude and longitude of a county.

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo Weather API](https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) uses WOEIDs to select location, and WOEIDs [exist for both cities and counties](http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/).